# How can I find the range and codomain for the function F

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let A={a,b,c},B={x,y,z},C={r,s,t} ...  Let f:A→B and g:B→C
 be defined by: f={(a,y)(b,x),(c,y)} and g={(x,s),(y,t),(z,r)}

How can I find the range of f and the codomain of f. ??

Comment: Hint: range of f = f(A); codomain of f is the *a priori* destination of A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The notation $f:A \rightarrow B$ indicates that $f$ is mapping elements fom the set $A$ to elements from the set $B$. That immediately tells you that the *codomain* is $B$. No need to look at which specific elements get mapped to which specific elements. It is, as the commenter expresses it, the *a priori* or *intended* destination. Think of it as the 'y-axis' when graphing some function $y=f(x)$

The *range* is the set of elements from the codomain that the function *actually* maps to. So now you do need to look at which elements map to which elements. So, looking at that, we see that the function maps to the elements $x$ and $y$ only (nothing gets mapped to $z$). Therefore, the range is $\{ x,y\}$